# Is the value of $event customisable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component, which listens out for the value of the selection from the dropdown and outputs it within a child component. The issue is is that the $event value is a ID number, I require a string which is the same as is outputted via '{{(type.name)}}'.

I have changed the input value to type.name, but this causes issues with other components in the app that rely on the value being an ID integer.

Is there a way to change the value being captured, to that of the string value being interpolated in {{(type.name)}} ?

NOTE: I have returned the this.event object to me, and the text value of the selection is not a property within it.

TEMPLATE:

```html
<b-select
    :v-model="documentType"
    @input="updateModel" 
>
    <optgroup
        v-for="group in allDocumentTypeGroups"
        :key="group.id"
        :label="t(group.name)"
    >
        <option
            v-for="type in group.documentTypes"
            :key="type.id"
            :value="type.id"
        >
            {{(type.name)}}
        </option>
    </optgroup>
</b-select>
```

METHODS:

```js
methods: {
    updateModel($event) {
        this.storage_Selection.push($event);
        this.$store.commit('addDocumentType', this.storage_Selection);
   }
}
```

Comment: $event is whatever considered select value. If it's id then $event is id. If you need to customize a component, wrap it with your own component and modify an event to whatever you need. This is a good practice to use a wrapper because you never know how if default behaviour will cause you troubles later.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ID to look up the name from `this.groups` in your `updateModel` handler. Something like (untested):

```js
methods: {
   updateModel(id) {
      const name = this.group.documentTypes.find(type => type.id == id)
      this.storage_Selection.push(name);
      this.$store.commit('addDocumentType', this.storage_Selection); 
   }
}
```